# Options to link DOM node to (in-browser) domain object: is direct reference OK?

Tags: javascript, dom

For a single-page app: I want each of my DOM nodes to have a reference to a single (in-browser) domain object. Is it OK to just store a direct reference like this:

```
var myDomainObject = ...;
var DOMNode = document.getElementById("myId");
DOMNode.domain_object = myDomainObject;
```

Is this safe, repeatable? Can the browser do mysterious things with added-on JavaScript properties?

Thanks.

Comment: You are much better off to do references the other way, i.e. from a native object to a DOM object. You might use an index or similar approach.

Comment: Just to clarify: some of my DOM nodes are visual representations of domain objects. It is for these nodes that I want to associate a single DOM node with a single domain object.

Comment: I guess you want to be able to respond to user actions on DOM elements and get the associated object. Much better to store a reference in the *className* or *data-* properties, that's what they're for. Note that the value of such properties should be a string literal, not an object reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an experiential standpoint: I've attached data directly to nodes without issue and never had a problem. From a specification standpoint, my interpretation is that doing so is not necessarily recommended, but is safe to the extent that the custom attributes don't conflict anything else.

In [Common Infrastructure - Extensibility](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/infrastructure.html#extensibility), the recommendation for authors (that's you) is to use only [data-*] attributes:

> Authors can include data for inline client-side scripts or server-side
>   site-wide scripts to process using the data-*="" attributes. These are
>   guaranteed to never be touched by browsers, and allow scripts to
>   include data on HTML elements that scripts can then look for and
>   process.

And the requirement for a valid user-agent is to leave anything in the DOM it doesn't recognize.

> User agents must treat elements and attributes that they do not
>   understand as semantically neutral; leaving them in the DOM (for DOM
>   processors), and styling them according to CSS (for CSS processors),
>   but not inferring any meaning from them.

So, my suggestion, along the same line as the W3C's aim of avoiding conflicts, is to create objects that refer *to* DOM elements. But, if you "must" tag weird things onto the DOM, rest assured that user agents are required to leave it there. But if you really must, it may be wise to use those `data-*` attributes!

(I personally don't use them and tend to slap objects and values onto whatever's most convenient at the time. But, I may be jaded by about 15 years of hacks and "feature detection" for the non-compliance of the user agents. Even now, I don't think IE supports the `data-*` standard ... )

Answer (score 2):

I've done it before to store custom events and it works fine in every browser I tried but yeah, it's dangerous I'd say, only if there are no other alternatives and you must pass this info *with* the element.

At least, ideally, create your own namespace to not pollute the already polluted object:

```
var myDomainObject = ...;
var DOMNode = document.getElementById("myId");
DOMNode.My = {};
DOMNode.My.domain_object = myDomainObject;
```

**Edit:** Just wanted to see how many methods and properties a regular `div` might have, and it has 136 (in Chrome). http://jsbin.com/abecaq/1/edit

Comment: +1 Also, while it "works" in most browsers in use, there's nothing in the DOM specs to say that you can add random properties to host objects.

Answer (score 0):

While it wouldn't cause any issues on a small site, I would avoid doing this for a few reasons...

1. You are opening yourself up to memory leaks by linking references to many different JS objects
2. Any new DOM nodes would have to have this link attached

I would recommend utilizing a global variable or ideally a variable at the highest necessary scope that can be referenced whenever necessary.

Comment: "You are opening yourself up to memory leaks". Any references for that?

Comment: @RobG I think he's referring to this: http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html ... an *old* bug. But also a bug that MS incorrectly claimed to have fixed several times. And, I honestly have no idea whether it's still an issue. I just assume it is ...

Comment: @svidgen—that is an old article about IE and circular references involving DOM elements. While it was not fully fixed in IE6 & 7, it is pretty much fixed in IE 8. And the OP doesn't create such circular references anyway.

Comment: @RobG wasn't referring to the IE bug specifically. More a general warning that linking objects should be handled with care. Say the linked object is no longer needed - without the link GC would unload it. But because it's linked to something else, the likelihood if it remaining in memory is increased. So, more of a friendly warning.